# How can I make diamonds disappear after collision in LIBGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

I'm creating a Java game similar to Mario Bros. I'm using Tiled Map Editor to put diamonds inside my game, so my character can collect these diamonds. But, I have a problem. I can't make the diamonds disappear after collision.

This is my code that I've used to remove the diamonds:

```
public TiledMapTileLayer.Cell getCell(){
    TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(8);
    return layer.getCell((int) (body.getPosition().x * MainGame.PPM / 64),
            (int) (body.getPosition().y * MainGame.PPM / 64))
}
```

This is my code that I have used for collision:

```
  if ("HARRY".equals(f1.getUserData()) && "COINS".equals(f2.getUserData())) {
        System.out.println("coins");
        if (f2.getUserData() instanceof Treasure) {
            System.out.println("Works");
            treasure.getCell().setTile(null);
  }
```

this if-statement doesn't work ( if (f2.getUserData() instanceof Treasure) )
If I use the code without this statement, just the first diamond that I've put it inside Tiled Map disappeared.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What happens with that if-statement? What do you mean with "It doesn't work"?